# chkconfig: 35 99 05? Explanation

Tags: shell

35 are the runlevels for the script start

99 and 05 is not understandable

Could some one explain the chkconfig parameters?

Run levels are from 0 to 6.

How this 99 parameter will work when used in the script?

Comment: Unclear.   Please specify the name of the script in question, as well as exactly what file contained, or which program outputed, each of these numbers: 0,5,6,35, 99.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the man page for chkconfig says,

> Each service which should be manageable by chkconfig needs two or more
>   commented lines added to its init.d script. The first line tells
>   chkconfig what runlevels the service should be started in by default,
>   as well as the start and stop priority levels. If the service should
>   not, by default, be started in any runlevels, a - should be used in
>   place of the runlevels list. The second line contains a description
>   for the service, and may be extended across multiple lines with
>   backslash continuation.
>
> For example, random.init has these three lines:

```
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: Saves and restores system entropy pool for \
#              higher quality random number generation.
```

> This says that the random script should be started in levels 2, 3, 4, and 5, that its
>   start priority should be 20, and that its stop priority should be 80.

Start and Stop priorities are used to determine what order initscripts are run in: when starting, lower numbers are run first, when stopping, higher numbers are shutdown first.

Comment: your explanation help me a lot in understanding my query